# How to make correct pagination in Vue.js 2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, pagination, vuex, bootstrap-5

I'm having trouble creating pagination with vue. My task is to make sure that when you click on the numbers of the buttons, new tasks from jsonplaceholder are loaded.

I have successfully loaded the first and second page. I assume this is related directly to my this.fetchTodos() action. I'm just learning vue and I need help figuring out how to update the data when moving to a new page without loading.

In this case, it is necessary that the url of the page changes (get request). My page state is changing, but posts are not loading when clicking on the third page.

Below is the code of four files that I think will help you understand the situation.

Maybe you will easier with [GitHub](https://github.com/bobrov-site/todolistvue), please check pagination branch

Thanks in advance for your help! If you have questions or need more information, write in the comments

TodoListView.vue - is starting page, where is todos fetching and rendered on page.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
<div class="todolist">
  <ContainerBootstrap>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <TitlePage v-if="todos" text="Список задач"/>
        <TitlePage v-else text="Список задач пуст, создайте новую!"/>
        <button-bootstrap data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#createTodo" css-class="btn-lg btn-primary mt-2 mb-4">Создать задачу</button-bootstrap>
        <ModalBootstrap @create="createTodo" :todos="todos" css-id="createTodo"/>
        <SearchBootstrap v-if="todos" @search="searchTodo"/>
        <div v-if="todos" class="d-flex justify-content-end mt-2">
          <button-bootstrap @click.native="setCompletedToAllTodo()" css-class="btn-lg btn-success">Отменить всё как "Выполненные"</button-bootstrap>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <TodoList v-if="todos" :todos="searchedTodos"/>
    <PaginationBootstrap :page="page" :total-pages="totalPages" class="mt-4"/>
  </ContainerBootstrap>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ContainerBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ContainerBootstrap";
import TitlePage from "@/components/TitlePage";
import TodoList from "@/components/TodoList";
import {mapState, mapActions, mapMutations, mapGetters} from 'vuex'
import ButtonBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ButtonBootstrap";
import ModalBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ModalBootstrap";
import SearchBootstrap from "@/components/UI/SearchBootstrap";
import PaginationBootstrap from "@/components/UI/PaginationBootstrap";
export default {
  name: "TodoListView",
  components: {
    PaginationBootstrap,
    SearchBootstrap, ModalBootstrap, TodoList , ButtonBootstrap, TitlePage, ContainerBootstrap},
  data: function() {
    return {
      isShow: false,
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchTodos: "todos/fetchTodos"
    }),
    ...mapMutations({
      setSearchQuery: 'todos/setSearchQuery'
    }),
    createTodo(todo) {
      this.$store.commit('todos/addTodo', todo);
    },
    setCompletedToAllTodo() {
      console.log('hello')
      this.$store.commit('todos/setCompletedToAllTodo')
    },
    searchTodo(query) {
      this.$store.state.todos.searchQuery = query;
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchTodos()
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      todos: state => state.todos.todos,
      isTodosLoading: state => state.todos.isTodosLoading,
      page: state => state.todos.page,
      limit: state => state.todos.limit,
      totalPages: state => state.todos.totalPages,
      searchQuery: state => state.todos.searchQuery
    }),
    ...mapGetters({
      searchedTodos: 'todos/searchedTodos'
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

TodoListPaginationView - is second file, where is loading second page and another when click on pagination.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
<div class="todolist">
  <ContainerBootstrap>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <TitlePage :text="'Страница №'+ page"/>
        <router-link to="/todolist">
          <button-bootstrap css-class="btn-lg btn-primary mt-2 mb-4">Вернуться к началу</button-bootstrap>
        </router-link>
      </div>
      <TodoList v-if="todos" :todos="searchedTodos"/>
      <PaginationBootstrap :page="page" :total-pages="totalPages" class="mt-4"/>
    </div>
  </ContainerBootstrap>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ContainerBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ContainerBootstrap";
import TitlePage from "@/components/TitlePage";
import ButtonBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ButtonBootstrap";
import TodoList from "@/components/TodoList";
import {mapActions, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapState} from "vuex";
import PaginationBootstrap from "@/components/UI/PaginationBootstrap";
export default {
  name: "TodoListPaginationView",
  components: {PaginationBootstrap, TodoList, ButtonBootstrap, TitlePage, ContainerBootstrap},
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchTodos: "todos/fetchTodos",
    }),
    ...mapMutations({
      setSearchQuery: 'todos/setSearchQuery'
    })
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      todos: state => state.todos.todos,
      isTodosLoading: state => state.todos.isTodosLoading,
      page: state => state.todos.page,
      limit: state => state.todos.limit,
      totalPages: state => state.todos.totalPages,
      searchQuery: state => state.todos.searchQuery
    }),
    ...mapGetters({
      searchedTodos: 'todos/searchedTodos'
    })
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchTodos()
  },
}
</script>
```

PaginationBootstrap.vue - third file, where is logic for pagination. Ui bootstrap 5 file.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination">
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Предыдущая</a></li>
      <li v-for="pageNumber in totalPages" :key="pageNumber" :class="{'active' : page === pageNumber}" class="page-item">
        <span @click="changePage(pageNumber)" class="page-link">{{pageNumber}}</span>
      </li>
      <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">Далее</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "PaginationBootstrap",
  props: {
    page: Number,
    totalPages: Number
  },
  methods: {
    changePage(pageNumber) {
      this.$store.commit('todos/setPage', pageNumber);
      if (pageNumber === 1) {
        this.$router.push('/todolist')
      }
      else {
        this.$router.push({name: 'todolistPagination', params: {page: pageNumber}})
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>

.pagination {
  .page-item {
    .page-link {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }
}

</style>
```

todosModule.js - last file, where is vuex logic for todos.

```html
import axios from "axios";
export const todosModule = {
    state: () => ({
        todos: [],
        page: 1,
        limit: 10,
        totalPages: 0,
        isTodosLoading: false,
        searchQuery: '',
    }),
    mutations: {
        setTodos(state, todos) {
            state.todos = todos
        },
        setPage(state, page) {
            state.page = page
        },
        setTotalPages(state, totalPages) {
            state.totalPages = totalPages
        },
        setLoadingTodos(state, bool) {
            state.isTodosLoading = bool
        },
        setCompleted(state, completed) {
            const index = state.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === completed.id);
            state.todos[index].completed = completed.completed
        },
        setCompletedToAllTodo(state) {
            state.todos.map(obj => {
                obj.completed = true
            })
        },
        removeTodo(state, id) {
            const index = state.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === id)
            state.todos.splice(index, 1)
        },
        addTodo(state, todo) {
            state.todos.unshift(todo);
        },
        setTitle(state, tusk) {
            const index = state.todos.findIndex(todo => todo.id === tusk.id);
            state.todos[index].title = tusk.title
        },
        setSearchQuery(state, searchQuery) {
            state.searchQuery = searchQuery;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        async fetchTodos({state, commit}) {
            try {
                commit('setLoadingTodos' , true)
                const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos', {
                    params: {
                        _page: state.page,
                        _limit: state.limit
                    }
                })
                commit('setTotalPages', Math.ceil(response.headers['x-total-count'] / state.limit))
                commit('setTodos', response.data)
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e)
            }
            finally {
                commit('setLoadingTodos', false)
            }
        },
        async getCurrentPage({commit}, currentPage) {
            try {
                commit('setPage', currentPage)
            }
            catch (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
        }
    },
    getters: {
      searchedTodos(state) {
          return [...state.todos].filter(todo => todo.title.toLowerCase().includes(state.searchQuery.toLowerCase()))
      },
    },
    namespaced: true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okey, I found solution for myself.

Most importent thing is watcher. I added to TodoListPaginationView.vue next code:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<template>
<div class="todolist">
  <ContainerBootstrap>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12 text-center">
        <TitlePage :text="'Страница №'+ page"/>
        <router-link to="/todolist">
          <button-bootstrap css-class="btn-lg btn-primary mt-2 mb-4">Вернуться к началу</button-bootstrap>
        </router-link>
      </div>
      <TodoList v-if="todos" :todos="searchedTodos"/>
      <PaginationBootstrap :page="page" :total-pages="totalPages" class="mt-4"/>
    </div>
  </ContainerBootstrap>
</div>
</template>

<script>
import ContainerBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ContainerBootstrap";
import TitlePage from "@/components/TitlePage";
import ButtonBootstrap from "@/components/UI/ButtonBootstrap";
import TodoList from "@/components/TodoList";
import {mapActions, mapGetters, mapMutations, mapState} from "vuex";
import PaginationBootstrap from "@/components/UI/PaginationBootstrap";
export default {
  name: "TodoListPaginationView",
  components: {PaginationBootstrap, TodoList, ButtonBootstrap, TitlePage, ContainerBootstrap},
  methods: {
    ...mapActions({
      fetchTodos: "todos/fetchTodos",
    }),
    ...mapMutations({
      setSearchQuery: 'todos/setSearchQuery'
    })
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      todos: state => state.todos.todos,
      isTodosLoading: state => state.todos.isTodosLoading,
      page: state => state.todos.page,
      limit: state => state.todos.limit,
      totalPages: state => state.todos.totalPages,
      searchQuery: state => state.todos.searchQuery
    }),
    ...mapGetters({
      searchedTodos: 'todos/searchedTodos'
    })
  },
  watch: {
    page: function (val) {
      if (val) {
        this.fetchTodos()
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.fetchTodos();
  },
}
</script>
```